# Background image not showing up

Tags: themes

Hey i am developing a wp theme from scratch.I want to set a background image.

So i have declared some  css code inside the body but it didnt works actually..

The code is

## header.php

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?> > 
<div id="avinash">
<header class = "firstclass">
<h1><a href="<?php home_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
<h2><?php bloginfo('description') ?> </h2>
</div> 


<nav class="mythirdclass">
<?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>
</nav>

</header>
```

## footer.php

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
<div class = "mysecondclass">
<footer class="asampleclass">
</footer>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

## style.css

```
body {
background: url('background.jpg') no-repeat top left;
}
```

The image `background.jpg` is in the same directory actually..But this code isnt working for me..

Any help would be appreciated..Thanx

Comment: if `background.jpg` is in same directory of `style.css` then it should work. You must have been doing some mistake. May be some other css rule in `style.css` overwriting body background.

Comment: @Roberthue no no its in the same directory..and i dont have any other css in my file

Comment: okay I think I got it.

Comment: @Roberthue then can you please post the answer if you got the idea on how to make it work

Comment: Your code should work, however try adding a `/` before the image path in CSS declaration.. `background: url('/background.jpg') no-repeat top left;`.

Comment: @Abhik i have added the declairation like  
`function afunction()  {
 wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'afunction');` on functions.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not create your `header.php` properly. You did not include `HTML doctype declaration` and head section.

So here is your `header.php`

```
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js">
  <head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
    <title><?php wp_title(''); ?><?php if(wp_title('', false)) { echo ' : '; } ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/style.css' media='all' />
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
  </head>
  <body <?php body_class(); ?>>

    <div id="avinash">

      <header class="firstclass">
          <h1><a href="<?php home_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
          <h2><?php bloginfo('description') ?></h2>
      </header> 

      <nav class="mythirdclass">
          <?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>
      </nav>

    </div>
```

And this should be your `footer.php`

```
    <div class="mysecondclass">
        <footer class="asampleclass">
        </footer>
    </div> 

    <?php wp_footer(); ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Now also make sure that you have included header and footer in your `index.php` and other theme pages and templates.

**EDIT**

It's working. only issue in `style.css` with image file path. Should be only `honey.jpg` without `/` if it's in same directory.

```
body {
    background: url('honey.jpg') no-repeat top left;
}
```

Comment: ..i have added the code but this isnt showing the background image

Comment: Make sure you have `wp_head()` in your header.php. Also, if you can send us a link where we can preview, we can evaluate further because now it's not possible to diagnose the issue without it.

Comment: can you test the code if i give my full code ..have you got installed apache on ur pc ??..so that you can test it

Comment: Sure, add a link to download complete theme zip.

Comment: i have added it ..please check the link http://www.mediafire.com/download/m8b83zczc5ic7de/mywptheme.zip

Comment: it would be realy greatfuL if you can help me ..:)

Comment: Just checked and it's working fine except the image path is wrong in `style.css`. Check edit in my answer. You should not add `/` if image is in same directory as `style.css` file.

Comment: i have removed the `/` but it still didnt showing me the background image .i dont know why ..:(

Comment: It means there is something wrong with your browser or WordPress installation. First clear cache and check, still same problem then try different browser, still issues then enable debug mode and check/fix for errors,  and if it still does not solve your issue, install new WordPress and try it.